# CakePHP generate and save PDF

Tags: cakephp, pdf

I am using CakePHP for an application that does auto generation of vouchers to a PDF file. But they work through user clicks. Now I wish to create it automatically and have the file written to the server hard disk. Then later on, these files will get zipped up and sent to an email of my choice.

For the PDFs I use Html2ps/Html2pdf component found in CakePHP. You can view it here http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Casmo/2010/06/26/creating-pdf-files-with-html2ps-html2pdf

One issue I have is the formatting doesn't look right. If I have links that look like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/this-is-my-perma-link

They will render this way in the generated PDF:

http://www.mydomain.com/this- is- my- perma- link

And that would be a broken link. I've tried to use other characters to replace the dash but it doesn't work. I am not sure why.

Another issue is, how can I write the generated PDF file to my server hard disk? Is there an option for me to do that and how do I define the destination. Any examples?

Maybe thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your code where you generate your link?

Comment: I use the Html Helper. Nothing really special here $linkURL = $this->Html->url($this->data['DocumentTemplate']['permalink']);

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can to use FPDF library . and you can to save file in the server and then redirect to other function.

check the next code.

///Call to library

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

require_once APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'fpdf17' . DS . 'fpdf.php';

class TestController extends AppController {
public function test(){

--Create fpdf.
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();


$pdf->Output('files/Report.pdf');  
$pdf->text($x,$y,'Txt');
return $this->redirect(
array('controller' => 'Test', 'action' => 'test_new')
);

}
}
```